# iOS Launch Image: set display time and customized file name?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two questions wrt the new iOS launch image:

1. The manual says that it can be from a xib file. how could one dynamically load the xib file? right now it is called the "launch xib" from latest version of xcode;
2. How could I set the time that launch image is going to display? I am trying to test in multi language environment, the launch image just flashes by me that it is hard to see if the page displayed correctly...especially when in a foreign language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the file used in the settings for your target under "Launch Screen File".

In order to test my launch screens I set a break point in the first line of my app delegate. This should pause execution of the app without going past the launch screen. You won't be able to rotate the view while like this, but you can rotate the device and reload if you need to test multiple orientations.

Comment: Here is what I did: 1. Added sleep(5) in AppDelegate:applicationDidFinishLaunching, this caused the launch screen to delay a bit (yep, breakpoint also works). 

I still have two questions: how to associate target action to the launch image, and how to dynamically load the launch image?

Right now it looks like that one has to set the launch image file name (launchimage.xib, for example) for "Launch screen file" field in build setting in order for that launchimage.xib to display.